# Mac's scrollbar too big to read one-liners

Tags: discussion, scrolling, mac, horizontal-scroll-bar

When reading code that is a one liner and is wide enough to scroll, the Mac's scrollbars that appear is too big makes it hard to read the code, that is behind it.

For example:

[image: Difficult to read]

It's not impossible but for UI its not good.

What can be done to address this problem?

---

**NOTE:** This might not reproduce on othe people's macs. I am using a Magic mouse with a 2011 iMac running Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion.

Test:

```
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what to do about it? Basically, this is a usability problem with OS X, not Stack Exchange.

Comment: You haven't mentioned a browser at any point - which is usually the culprit rather than your OS (unless you've customised the life out of it's UI) and your browser can't cope.

Comment: @nickhar: True - Firefox draws its own scrollbars that avoid this problem completely but for a browser that uses native scrollbars this is a problem which I can reproduce on my Mac when I enable autohiding of scrollbars.

Comment: @nickhar I am using Safari

Comment: @slhck I think we should make the code box a bit larger for browsers that use native scroll bars or turn them off if you can